# Devise-managed session not propagating to subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise to manage authentication in a Rails 3.1 application. It works just fine in my production server. But I just set up a new test server, and if I log in to the main site, accessing a subdomain is not recognizing the session. It's asking me to log in again.

I can't recall where I would troubleshoot this information. It seems as if it is some cookie setting.

I have domains pointed to each site, production and test. The production one ends in .net, the test version ends in .co.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not a devise setting but a session and cookie setting.

You can work on this by setting the variable `YourApp::Application.config.session`

You can do this in your `environment.rb` file or your `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. Example for session_store.rb is

```
YourApp::Application.config.session = {
 :session_domain => '.yourdomain.com',
 :session_key => '_yourapp',
 :expire_after => 14*24*3600,
 #:secure => true, #for secure/ssl sessions and such
 :secret      => 'somesecretgobledygook' 
}
```

Please note the `session_domain` setting it to `.yourdomain.com` makes your cookies work across subdomains.

This applies to sessions. There are similiar settings for cookies.