# devise throw me out right after sign in on production but working great on development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using rails 3.2 and Devise 3.4.1.
On development environment all is working great but on production I'm getting this:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 111.111.111.11 at 2015-01-18 15:04:58 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PGRrSKfVz8fZiv1a1qBJN2TzmFRAvUgEfYRpmdWiPWk=", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'email@email.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2015-01-18 15:04:53', `current_sign_in_at` = '2015-01-18 15:04:59', `sign_in_count` = 25, `updated_at` = '2015-01-18 15:04:59' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://subdomain.domain.com/
Completed 302 Found in 100.0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 111.111.111.11 at 2015-01-18 15:04:59 +0000
Started GET "/authorized" for 111.111.111.11 at 2015-01-18 15:04:59 +0000
Processing by AuthorizedController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0.3ms
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 111.111.111.11 at 2015-01-18 15:05:00 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5.3ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

as you can see the user is being authorised but signing out immediately after that.

help?

Comment: `user is being authorised` proof?

Comment: you can see that the `last_sign_in_at` value is being updated and redirect to "\authorized" before getting 401

Comment: Are you sure the user was activated?

Comment: Check your production cookie settings

Also visit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949810/devise-managed-session-not-propagating-to-subdomains

Comment: If you see . Call is made to authorized controller and response is unauthorized. Please paste your authorized controller code. That is where authorization is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the CDN just blocked Devise's cookie so it's solved now

thank you all!